# How to display different information in the same html based on previous selected link using jsp?

Tags: jsp

I currently have a project list page that shows all the projects, and it should allow users to click on the project name to view the details of the selected project.

The following code check all the project names from database then return and display the project list:

```
<table border="1" width="50%" cellpadding="5">
    <tr>
        <th align= left>Project Name</th>
    </tr>   
<%
    List<String> projectList = DatabaseFunctionalities.showAdminProjectList();

    for(String p: projectList){
        out.print("<tr><td><a href=\"Project.jsp\">" + p+ "</a></td></tr>");
    }   
%>
</table>
```

The problem that I have is how to let the project page know what the information should be displayed according to the project that is selected?

Comment: In order for someone to help you, it's important to discuss in the question what you've tried so far up to this point to solve this challenge.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
out.print("<tr><td><a href=\"Project.jsp?project=" + p+ "\">" + p+ "</a></td></tr>");
```

You can get a project name by `request.getParameter("project")` in Project.jsp.

Comment: Is `request.getParameter("project")` null?

Comment: yes, <% String p = request.getParameter("project");
  out.println(p);
%> shows null in Project.jsp

Comment: Is it because I didnt use <form action="Project.jsp">? I am not sure if that's the problem. If yes, where should i add the code at?

Comment: Please show your page source by right clicking on your page. And copy and paste `<table>` tag and `<form>` tag here.

Comment: Somehow it works now > < i think maybe there's a typo... Thank you so much for helping!!